# boost::asio timeouts example - writing data is expensive

Tags: boost-asio

boost:: asio provides an example of how to use the library to implement asynchronous timeouts; client sends server periodic heartbeat messages to server, which echoes heartbeat back to client. failure to respond within N seconds causes disconnect.  see boost_asio/example/timeouts/server.cpp
The pattern outlined in these examples would be a good starting point for part of a project i will be working on shortly, but for one wrinkle:
in addition to heartbeats, both client and server need to send messages to each other. 
The timeouts example pushes heartbeat echo messages onto a queue, and a subsequent timeout causes an asynchronous handler for the timeout to actually write the data to the socket.

Introducing data for the socket to write cannot be done on the thread running io_service, because it is blocked on run(). run_once() doesn't help, you still block until there is a handler to run, and introduce the complexity of managing work for the io_service.
In asio, asynchronous handlers - writes to the socket being one of them - are called on the thread running io_service.

Therefore, to introduce messages randomly, data to be sent is pushed onto a queue from a thread other than the io_service thread, which implies protecting the queue and notification timer with a mutex. There are then two mutexes per message, one for pushing the data to the queue, and one for the handler which dequeues the data for write to socket.

This is actually a more general question than asio timeouts alone: is there a pattern, when the io_service thread is blocked on run(), by which data can be asynchronously written to the socket without taking two mutexes per message?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need two mutexes, don't you only need one to protect the message queue in the case the io_service is already sending a message. As for the handler, you can use the same mutex to protect the queue. Unless you are invoking io_service::run from multiple threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following things could be of interest: [boost::asio strands](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html) is a mechanism of synchronising handlers. You only need to do this though if you are calling io_service::run from multiple threads AFAIK.

Also useful is the [io_service::post](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html) method, which allows you execute code from the thread that has invoked io_service::run.

Comment: thanks for the info. I took a look at these before asking the question; the post method seems not helpful because the signature of the handler must be void handler(void); no data can be passed in. I need to look at strands more carefully, but the writing of data onto the queue does not happen in a handler, so how do strands help?

Comment: You can use boost::bind (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind/bind.html) to bind arbitrary data to a method.

Comment: +1 `io_service::post` and `boost::bind` is the way to go here, @user658878 you likely do not need a separate thread.